# MongoDB get data into java object

Tags: java, mongodb

I am quite new to MongoDb. i use a find and get the result in JSON format.

```
{"Name": "Harshil", "Age":20}
```

so what i need is parse this in java and get values in the variables.

```
String name should contain Harshil
int age should contain 20
```

is there a way to store these details in JAVA object?

Comment: What context are you using this in? If you're using Spring, Spring Data MongoDB will handle this for you magically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to connect to the your MongoDB:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017); //with default server and port adress
DB db = client.getDB( "your_db_name" );
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("Your_Collection_Name");
```

After the connecting you can pull your data from the server.Below, i assume that your document has Name and Age field :

```
DBObject dbo = collection.findOne();
String name = dbo.get("Name");
int age = dbo.get("Age");
```

Comment: You'll need to cast the results of the get, e.g. String name = (String)dbo.get("Name")

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It converts JSON to Java objects and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways and tools, one of which is [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public Person() {
        // no-args constructor
    }
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Person person = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

And I'd feel lax if I didn't add this [link](http://nyeggen.com/post/2013-10-18-the-genius-and-folly-of-mongodb) too.

Comment: feel lax means?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it with the Java driver :

```
DBObject dbo = ...
String s = dbo.getString("Name")
int i = dbo.getInt("Age")
```

Using another framework on top of the Java driver should be considered I you have multiple objects to manage.

Answer (score 1):

As we don't want to use the deprecated methods so, you can use the following code to do so:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("your_db_name");

MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("your_collection_name");

FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find();
MongoCursor<Document> dbc = iterDoc.iterator();

while(dbc.hasNext()){
try {
         JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(dbc.next().toJson());
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

         Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonParser, Person.class);
         String name = person.get("Name");
         String age = person.get("Age");

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JsonFactory, JsonParser,etc. are being used from Jackson to de-serialize the Document to the related Entity object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considere [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki)?

```
@Entity
class Person{
   @Property("Name") Date name;
   @Property("Age") Date age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Newer Way [Since getDB() is Deprecated]

Since the original answer was posted the `DBObject` and corresponding method `client.getDB` have been deprecated. For anyone who may be looking for a solution since the new update I have done my best to translate.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017); //Location by Default
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("YOUR_DATABASE_NAME");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME");
```

Once connected to the document there are numerous familiar methods of getting data as a Java Object. Assuming you plan to have multiple documents that contain a persons `name` and their `age` I suggest collecting all the documents (which you can visualize as rows containing a name and age) in an ArrayList then you can simply pick through the documents in the `ArrayList` to convert them to java objects as so:

```
List<Document> documents = (List<Document>) collection.find().into(new ArrayList<Document>());
for (Document document : documents) {
     Document person = documents.get(document);
     String name = person.get("Name");
     String age = person.get("Age");
}
```

Honestly the `for` loop is not a pretty way of doing it but I wanted to help the community struggling with deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using the new Mongodb Java API. It's very clean and clear.

```
public MyEntity findMyEntityById(long entityId) {

    List<Bson> queryFilters = new ArrayList<>();
    queryFilters.add(Filters.eq("_id", entityId));
    Bson searchFilter = Filters.and(queryFilters);

    List<Bson> returnFilters = new ArrayList<>();
    returnFilters.add(Filters.eq("name", 1));

    Bson returnFilter = Filters.and(returnFilters);

    Document doc = getMongoCollection().find(searchFilter).projection(returnFilter).first();

    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(doc.toJson());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    MyEntity myEntity = mapper.readValue(jsonParser, MyEntity.class);

    return myEntity;
}
```

Details at 
http://ashutosh-srivastav-mongodb.blogspot.in/2017/09/mongodb-fetch-operation-using-java-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this function to convert JSON returned by mongodb to your custom java object list.

```
MongoClient mongodb = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongodb.getDB("customData-database");
DBCursor customDataCollection = db.getCollection("customDataList").find();
List<CustomJavaObject>  myCustomDataList = null; // this list will hold your custom data
JSON json = new JSON();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
  //this is where deserialiazation(conversion) takes place
  myCustomDataList = objectMapper.readValue(json.serialize(customDataCollection),
      new TypeReference<List<Restaurant>>() {
      });
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

CustomJavaObject:

```
public class CustomJavaObject{
//your json fields go here
String field1, field2;
int num;
ArrayList<String> attributes;

//....write relevantgetter and setter methods
}
```

sample json:

```
 {
"field1": "Hsr Layout",
"field2": "www.google.com",
"num": 20,
"attributes": [
  "Benagaluru",
  "Residential"
]
},
{
"field1": "BTM Layout",
"field2": "www.youtube.com",
"num": 10,
"attributes": [
  "Bangalore",
  "Industrial"
]
}
```